# Swift - Failed (found nil) calling reloadData() from another class but succeeded from self class

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview, xcode10, swift4.2

I'm apparently designing a drag and drop dropbox which can either **select files by clicking it or dragging and dropping the files on it**, and I want the selected files to be visible in a table next to it. My design logic is that whenever the user selects files from an `NSOpenPanel`, it passes the selected file paths into the `CoreData` and then an array retrieves them one by one from the `CoreData`, and finally, update the `NSTableView`'s content by using `reloadData()`.

Basically, my problem is that whenever I try to call `ViewController().getDroppedFiles()` from `DropboxButton` class, I always get a `Fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value.`

My ViewController.swift:

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController, NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        getDroppedFiles()
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var DroppedFilesTableView: NSTableView!

    var droppedFiles: [DroppedFiles] = [] // Core Data class definition: DroppedFiles

    func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
        return droppedFiles.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {
        let droppedFilesCollection = droppedFiles[row]

        if (tableView?.identifier)!.rawValue == "fileNameColumn" {
            if let fileNameCell = tableView.makeView(withIdentifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "fileNameCell")) as? NSTableCellView {
                fileNameCell.textField?.stringValue = droppedFilesCollection.fileName!
                return fileNameCell
            }
        }  else if (tableView?.identifier)!.rawValue == "filePathColumn" {
             if let filePathCell = tableView.makeView(withIdentifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "filePathCell")) as? NSTableCellView {
                 filePathCell.textField?.stringValue = droppedFilesCollection.filePath!
                 return filePathCell
             }
        }
        return nil
    }

    @IBAction func DropboxClicked(_ sender: NSButton) {
        // selected file paths
        for filePath in selectedFilePaths {
            if let context = (NSApp.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.persistentContainer.viewContext {
                let droppedFilesData = DroppedFiles(context: context)
                droppedFilesData.fileName = getFileName(withPath: filePath)
                droppedFilesData.filePath = filePath
                do {
                    try context.save()
                } catch {
                    print("Unable to save core data.")
                }
            }
            getDroppedFiles()
        }
    }

    func getDroppedFiles() {
        if let context = (NSApp.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.persistentContainer.viewContext {
            do {
                try droppedFiles = context.fetch(DroppedFiles.fetchRequest())
            } catch {
                print("Unable to fetch core data.")
            }
        }
        DroppedFilesTableView.reloadData() // Fatal Error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value (whenever I call this function in other class)
    }


}
```

I'm using a push button (`NSButton`) as the dropbox (it has its own class), which can easily be clicked and also supports dragging options.

My DropboxButton.swift:

```
import Cocoa

class DropboxButton: NSButton {

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        registerForDraggedTypes([NSPasteboard.PasteboardType.URL, NSPasteboard.PasteboardType.fileURL])
    }

    override func draggingEntered(_ sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> NSDragOperation {
        // some other codes
        return .copy
    }

    override func draggingExited(_ sender: NSDraggingInfo?) {
        // some other codes
    }

    override func draggingEnded(_ sender: NSDraggingInfo) {
        // some other codes
    }

    override func performDragOperation(_ sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> Bool {
        guard let pasteboard = sender.draggingPasteboard.propertyList(forType: NSPasteboard.PasteboardType(rawValue: "NSFilenamesPboardType")) as? NSArray,
            let filePaths = pasteboard as? [String] else {
                return false
        }

        for filePath in filePaths {
            if let context = (NSApp.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.persistentContainer.viewContext {
                let droppedFilesData = DroppedFiles(context: context)
                droppedFilesData.fileName = getFileName(withPath: filePath)
                droppedFilesData.filePath = filePath
                do {
                    try context.save()
                } catch {
                    print("Unable to save core data.")
                }
            }
            ViewController().getDroppedFiles() // found nil with reloadData() in ViewController.swift
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

And this is my interface and code logic:
[image: user interface and code logic]

So, how can I `reloadData()` for the table view in my ViewController class from another class (`DropboxButton: NSButton`) so that whenever the user drags and drops files into the dropbox, the table view will reload?

P.S. To get this done means a lot to me, I really need to get this fixed in a short time, is there anyone can spend some time and help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `getDroppedFiles()` on a loaded instance of `ViewController`.

With `ViewController().getDroppedFiles()` you're creating a new instance of `ViewController` that is not shown anywhere (so controls are not initialized resulting in the nil error).

Comment: Oh, I think I understand! So, do you mean that I should instantiate the loaded ViewController in order to call that function?

Comment: Looking at your diagram, I would let the button generate an event to which the viewcontroller is listening so that the viewcontroller can call getDroppedFiles()

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution useful for my case.

I used observer to pass through data and call functions from other controller classes, now I understand that I was creating a new instance of `ViewController` which is not loaded. Here is my code:

ViewController.swift:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {
    // other codes
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(getDroppedFiles), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "reloadTableViewData"), object: nil)
    }
    @objc func getDroppedFiles() {
        DroppedFilesTableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

DropboxButton.swift:

```
class DropboxButton: NSButton {
    // other codes
    override func performDragOperation(_ sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> Bool {
        // other codes
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "reloadTableViewData"), object: nil)
        return true
    }
}
```

And now, everything works perfectly, I can even add an `userInfo:` to pass data between files and classes.